# Data Flow left outer Join results in empty data set when executed, but not on debuging

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a Left outer join configured between two data sets. When executed, the Join shows no results, although when debugging it does. Both dataset of the join contains data and the condition is fulfilled, although with a left outer join I would expect at least the content from the first data set.

[image]

The dataflow pipeline contains two similar joins and in both we have the same behavior.

The datasets involved in the join contains from 20K to 60K records. However, the flow loads a couple of datasets around 1 million records. We would expect some error if this was related to memory though...

Comment: I think the debug session's default behaviour is simply SELECT TOP 1000 records from the source datasets. Is it possible for you to replicate the debug session behaviour by creating separate TOP 1000 testing datasets; execute the pipeline on the new datasets and see if is also produce no results? (i.e. like the behaviour of using normal datasets)

Comment: Can you please add some more details for our clear understanding. Is the flow run successful ? where are you not seeing results ? in sink or just in pipeline run diagnostic summary ? if you are able to see in debug preview - your flow is working.  I see from your snip that join transformation was success with 41 columns . Can you check for join metrics in the out preview as you see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efVk7.png) & [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0svhh.png)